# how to display date format as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Z in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

Can you please suggest me how to display date format for a date column as `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Z` format in ssrs ?

I have googled but i am not getting exact format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering how to do this(how to display date in UTC format `('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')`. But in Sql Server 2012 it's too easy. Can be done like this. 
In Sql query we can do like below

```
SELECT EmpName, FORMAT(ApprovedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z') as ApprovedDate From Employee
```

Or in SSRS report expression we can do like below

```
Format(Fields!ApprovedDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:dd" & " Z")
```

> EmpName and ApprovedDate are the columns of Employee Table.

Hope this might be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

```
=System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(First(Fields!NOW.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
=Format(Fields!FeildName.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```